# Javascript “let” on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, var, let

On JSFiddle, the `let` command is not working correctly. If I do this simple code:

```
function hi(){
    var text = "hi";
    alert(text);
}
hi();
```

It works fine, and alerts “hi”. However, if I use

```
function hi(){
    let text = "hi";
    alert(text);
}
hi();
```

JSHint says “missing semicolon” on line 2. What’s happening? Am I using `let` wrong?

Comment: The let keyword is only available to code blocks in HTML wrapped in a <script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"> block (or higher version). XUL script tags have access to these features without needing this special block.

Answer (score 0):

First set the language to Javascript (this is the default), make sure you're not using Javascript 1.7!
Add the  `"use strict";` line before your code, update fiddle and finally run!